# Test a class's method(s) in different test classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have an orchestrator class which has one method implements a feature via calling multiple methods:

```
public class Orchestrator {
    public void doImportantStuff(){
       firstDoThis();
       thenDoThis();
       finallyDoThis();        
    }

    private void firstDoThis(){
       ...
    }

    private void thenDoThis(){
       ...
    }

    private void finallyDoThis(){
       ...
    }
}
```

My question is, I have lots of cases to test for all methods called from doImportantStuff() so I'm planning to write separate test classes for each method. Is it something I should avoid, or does it sounds good?

Answer (score 0):

This actually depends on which kind of tests you are about to write. Unit-testing assumes you test each method in isolation, but integration test will test all-in-one.

Assuming the methods do contain some business logic I'd recomment to write a set of unit tests for each of the method (maybe moving them into separate classes to comply the Single Responsibility principle).

After you are sure that all the methods works fine, it is time to write an integration test and test how the logic integrates (e.g. the particular call order). BTW, here could be useful some mocking tools as you are not going to test each method again.